# String Function in Excel

Tags: excel, string, formula

Here are the sample text:

Input:

```
1. AbST/1234342
2. Y_sRR/666
3. B.RE/1234
```

Output:

```
1. AST
2. YRR
3. BRE
```

Basically I need a formula to get the first three capital letters before the slash and disregard lowercase and symbols.

Comment: Almost trivial with VBA. Almost impossible without. In any event, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this could be done without VBA, but with VBA it is straightforward enough:

```
Function ExtractUppers(s As String, k As Long) As String
    'Extracts the first k upper case letters from
    's, returning the result as a string
    'if there are fewer than k, the function returns
    'those that are found

    Dim letters As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim c As String
    ReDim letters(0 To k - 1) As String
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If "A" <= c And c <= "Z" Then
            letters(j) = c
            j = j + 1
            If j = k Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    ExtractUppers = Join(letters, "")
End Function
```

Then, for example, `=ExtractUppers("B.RE/1234",3)` would evaluate to `"BRE"`.

Comment: Nice, I did not know about the comparison between chars like that!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 / Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use the **array** formula:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&FIND("/",A1)-1)),1))>=65)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&FIND("/",A1)-1)),1))<=90),MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&FIND("/",A1)-1)),1),"")),3),"")
```

As pointed out by @JvdV, you can replace the `TEXTJOIN` function with the `CONCAT` function which is simpler when a delimiter is not required:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(CONCAT(IF((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&FIND("/",A1)-1)),1))>=65)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&FIND("/",A1)-1)),1))<=90),MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&FIND("/",A1)-1)),1),"")),3),"")
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

If you do not have the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use a User Defined Function written in VBA.

Here is an example using Regular Expressions:

```
Option Explicit
Function upper3(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim I As Long, sTemp As String

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = False
    .Pattern = "[A-Z](?=.*/)"
    Set MC = .Execute(S)
    If MC.Count >= 3 Then
        For I = 0 To 2
            sTemp = sTemp & MC(I)
        Next I
        upper3 = sTemp
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Either gives the following results:

[image]

However, the formula will return 1-3 uppercase letters preceding the `/`; the UDF only returns a result if there are at least 3 uppercase letters preceding the `/`. Either can be changed to the other depending on your requirements.

Comment: Nice Ron, also if user does have access to `TEXTJOIN`, he should also have access to `CONCAT` which might be less hassle.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks. I had forgotten about that function. I'll add it with credit

Answer (score 1):

Here is another formula option if you have access to [`CONCAT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) function. Check the link for more information.

---

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=CONCAT(IF(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1))=TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$65:$A$90)),MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),""))
```

> ***NOTE:*** It's an array formula that you need to enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

I have not taken into consideration the `"/"` as though it seems there are not going to be capitals after it in your sample data. If there are, you have to replace the above formula with:

```
=CONCAT(IF(CODE(MID(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,SEARCH("/",A1))),1))=TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$65:$A$90)),MID(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,SEARCH("/",A1))),1),""))
```